# Atualizar pagina sem perder o valor de uma variavel

Tags: php, angularjs, socket, push-notification

Tenho um vetor que recebe dados vindo de um socket que utilizo para notificações ao usuario, porem toda vez que vou mudar de pagina eu perco todo o valor vindo dessa variavel, estou utilizando angular no front-end.
Como faço para que eu possa navegar normalmente no sistema sem que eu perca os valores dentro do meu vetor?
PS: Se alguem souber de alguma logica, tutorial referente a angular e notificações (estilo facebbok, twitter, etc), pode me passar que vou estudar.
Obrigado

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php uma opção...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma service e armazenar nela, pois quando a pagina é atualizada a service não é reiniciada.

```
    angular.module('app', [''])
  .service('myService', myService);

  function myService($http) {
    var dados;

    function setDados(valor) {
      dados = valor;
    }

    function getDados() {
      return dados
    }

  }
```

Apos isso é só injetar a service na sua controladora e acessar as funções

```
angular.module('heroApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl)

  function myCtrl($scope, myService) {
    var contato = {
      email:'teste@cc.cc',
      nome:'Fulano'
    }

    myService.setDados(contato);

    console.log(myService.getDados())

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse exemplo, ilustra a criação básica de uma sessão ancorada em variável global. Porém o uso exagerado de variáveis globais traz riscos graves aplicação. Os comentários  acima um colega indica um material de estudo  de `$_SESSION` Sugiro que estude isso antes de implementar. Também esse [Link](https://www.codigofonte.net/dicas/php/124_veja-como-usar-sessions-no-php). Espero ter ajudado bom estudo.

```
      <?php
      session_start();

      $st=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from usuarios where login='$doc'");
      $result=mysqli_fetch_array($st);

      $_SESSION['usuario'] = $result['nome'];
  ?>
<html>
 <head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    if ($_SESSION['usuario'] === false){
      Session_destroy();
      header("location: index"); exit;
    }
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><?php  echo $_SESSION['usuario'] ?> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="editarperfil">Editar</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout">Sair</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    ?>
</body>
```